# Custom query for wp_posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I created a custom query for wp_posts from wordpress and i need to know if its right because i received an error on this line:

```
   <li><a href="the_permalink()"> the_title() </a></li>
```

The error sounds like this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Good. My code looks like this, i mean my "custom" query for wp_posts:

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_title LIKE '%$name_query%' OR post_content LIKE '%$instit_query%' OR post_content LIKE '%$spec_query%' OR post_content LIKE '%$zone_query%' ORDER by post_title"); 
$myposts = get_posts( $result);
foreach( $result as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
<li><a href="the_permalink()"> the_title() </a></li>
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I dont think that will do what i want it to do so i need some help, please, how can i display the posts that i queried in the $results variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to output html you need to either stop processing the php at the output part, or you need to echo it as a string.

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"> ' . get_the_title() . ' </a></li>'
```

or

```
foreach ($result as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_title() ?> </a></li><?php
}
```